# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "git rm --cached" y "git reset HEAD"?

Tags: git

Por lo que tengo entendido, estos dos comandos funcionan de maneras distintas pero no logro ver la diferencia:

- `git rm --cached (archivo)`
- `git reset HEAD (archivo)`

Estuve probando en mi PC y a simple vista parecen lo mismo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las diferencias son las siguientes:

- `git rm --cached <file>`: remueve el archivo del indice, esto quiere decir, que **Git** ya no le hará seguimiento. Aunque el archivo seguirá existiendo en tu directorio, tal y como está.
- `git reset HEAD <file>`: devuelve el archivo a su último commit y este sigue en seguimiento por git, es decir podras hacer `add`, `commit`, etc. con total normalidad.

Si realizas `git status` podrás darte cuenta de que el archivo al que le aplicaste `git rm --cached <file>` ya no se encuentra en seguimiento por Git porque ya no aparece.

Answer (score 1):

git rm --cached: Elimina los archivos de nuestro repositorio local y del área de staging, pero los mantiene en nuestro disco duro. Básicamente le dice a Git que deje de trackear el historial de cambios de estos archivos, por lo que pasaran a un estado untracked.

git reset HEAD: Este es el comando para sacar archivos del área de staging. No para borrarlos ni nada de eso, solo para que los últimos cambios de estos archivos no se envíen al último commit, a menos que cambiemos de opinión y los incluyamos de nuevo en staging con git add, por supuesto.