# Diferencia entre git rm --cached y git restore --staged

Tags: git

Es que a mi parecer hacen lo mismo, sacar los archivos del staging area hacia el directorio de trabajo, pero hay algo que los diferencie?

Comment: `git rm --cached` no hace eso. Lo que hace es borrar el archivo **en el índice** (para que quede borrado cuando hagas la siguiente revisión) pero dejando el archivo sin tocarlo en el árbol de trabajo.

Comment: ¡Quizás esto te pueda servir [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “git rm --cached” y “git reset HEAD”?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/387775/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-git-rm-cached-y-git-reset-head)!

Answer (score 0):

git rm --cached: Elimina los archivos de nuestro repositorio local y del área de staging, pero los mantiene en nuestro disco duro. Básicamente le dice a Git que deje de trackear el historial de cambios de estos archivos, por lo que pasaran a un estado untracked.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).